# compare between the number of dots for 2 strings

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I try to compare between two string .
a=1.22.33
b=2.1.33
we can see that the pattern is different:
22 contain 2 number
1 contain 1 number.
my code just compare the first item of the second string and not work on all the loop.

```
import re
def aa(a,g):
    b=re.split(r'\.', a)
    bb=re.split(r'\.', g)
    c=[]
    e=[]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        c.append(b[i])
        dd=c
    for j in range(len(bb)):
        e.append(bb[j])
        f=e
    for i in dd:
        if len(i) != len(f[j]):
            return True
        else:
            return False 
#call function
d="66.22.33"
u="66.2.33"
print(aa(d,u))
```

the result is false and we not that this is a mistake :
22 contain 2 number
1 contain 1 number.

Comment: ... what are you trying to do? Sorry, but I cannot discern what your code is attempting to do... it seems to copy a few lists in a weird way and store the lists in some variables, then it reuses indices so that the last loop comparse all the elements of a list to only the last element of the other... not sure what `True` or `False` means here as a result value

Comment: there's no need to pull `re` if you got string's `split()` sufficient.

Comment: I  tried to compare how many letter we have between each one of the dots , for example the first string 66.22.33 we know that the number between the dots is : 2,2,2
and for the string :"66.2.33"  number between the dots is 2,1,2 
so we can see that second item its not equal 1!=2 .

Comment: @danboor OK, I guessed right. Do you understand my solution?

Comment: @danboor can you edit the question and add this explanation what you are trying to do? All information should be in a question body.

Comment: thanks for your solution its smart, can you explain base on my solution what I need to do 
to get correct results?
I will edit the question as you ask

Comment: @danboor OK, one more thing. Do you want that function to return True when strings DON'T match?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find if substrings contained between dots are the same length:

```
d="66.22.33"
u="66.2.33"
compare(d, u)
>>> False

d="66.22.33"
u="66.11.33"
compare(d, u)
>>> True
```

Then you can check it this way:

```
def compare(a, b):
    a = a.split('.')
    b = b.split('.')
    return all(len(i) == len(j) for i, j in zip(a,b))
```

Comment: I try your solution I got result just for the first item not for all

Comment: @danboor What do you mean by "first item"?